# jboss shutdown not happening, stuck at message: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, jboss

> 2010-01-30 03:25:27,598 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase] Closing WebApplicationContext of Spring FrameworkServlet 'expertx'
>   2010-01-30 03:25:27,696 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase] Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext

are the last few lines in my server log. looking for "Shutdown complete" to be posted instead.

Answer (score 2):

Those two lines are logged by `org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader`, just before it calls `close()` on your application context.

You likely have a bean in the app context which is not responding to the `close()`, but from your description it's impossible to tell what that might be.

My suggestion is to the ramp up your log4j logging to DEBUG level, and then try the shutdown again. Spring will log an entry for each bean it tries to shutdown, and hopefully you'll be able to see the one that's blocking. If it's not obvious, then edit your question to include every Spring DEBUG-level log entry you see after the "Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext" one.